# Chrome: Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to return all window instances within a Chrome Extension, but I get:

> Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Invocation of form windows.getAll() doesn't match definition windows.getAll(optional object getInfo, function callback)

I've stripped my app down to the bare minimum, the following is my actual setup when I get the error message. The intent is that when I press the space bar, `chrome.windows.getAll()` gets called and something shows up in the background console. I do get "Message received" in the console before the error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or even what the error means? I've left the exact error message at the bottom

My Chrome version is: `33.0.1750.152`

---

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":         "Alt Tilde",
    "version":      "0.0.1",

    "background": {
        "scripts":  ["js/bg.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":  ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":       ["js/content.js"]
    }]
}
```

#### js/content.js

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: 'switch-window'})
})
```

#### js/bg.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(){
    console.log('Message received')
    console.log(chrome.windows.getAll())
})
```

---

### Full Error Message

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Invocation of form windows.getAll() doesn't match definition windows.getAll(optional object getInfo, function callback)
    at Object.normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (extensions::schemaUtils:113:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (extensions::binding:307:30)
    at chrome-extension://aijclfleiopkccfielfjknhgpajnclah/js/bg.js:2:32
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:394:22)
    at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:378:27)
    at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:400:17)
    at messageListener (extensions::messaging:192:31)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:394:22) extensions::event_bindings:382
Event.dispatch_ extensions::event_bindings:382
Event.dispatch extensions::event_bindings:400
messageListener extensions::messaging:192
Event.dispatchToListener extensions::event_bindings:394
Event.dispatch_ extensions::event_bindings:378
Event.dispatch extensions::event_bindings:400
dispatchOnMessage extensions::messaging:307
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a callback if you want to get all tab information.

Try this:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(wins){
  wins.forEach(function(win){
    win.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      console.log(tab.url);
    });
  });
});
```

And remember to add "tabs" permission in manifest if you want to fetch tab information.

Comment: That totally did it! The bit that was throwing me off was that the  [the manual for getAll](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll) says it's optional, so it didn't even occur to me to try